# Heroku Nodejs server crash without response

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

when i send a get request to my heroku node server it returns with response 200 But when i'm trying post request it throws this error

```
2019-04-29T19:02:31.366969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/login" host=pepperkart-b.herokuapp.com request_id=ee1a1430-6bad-45bc-9550-e5add2a5f028 fwd="43.248.69.3" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=122ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-04-29T19:02:31.361929+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-29T19:02:31.361945+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
2019-04-29T19:02:31.361947+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
2019-04-29T19:02:31.361949+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-29T19:02:31.361951+00:00 app[web.1]: No callback function was given.
```

I tried this on my localhost. My server is running smoothly there.

Comment: The cause of above error is that you use  new  MySQL database (version >= 8.x). Old  MySQL versions (5.x) use the authentication plugin such as  SHA256_PASSWORD. The  MySQL 8.x version uses the authentication plugin such as SHA2_PASSWORD.  NodeJS MySQL library hasn't changed yet. It uses the authentication plugin such as SHA256_PASSWORD, and has not supported  SHA2_PASSWORD.

Comment: @svikramjeet so what I should do now?